# How to set price scale on Trading View library?

Tags: javascript, tradingview-api

I have implement chart view with Trading View library - [Charting & Trading Platform](https://www.tradingview.com/HTML5-stock-forex-bitcoin-charting-library/?feature=charting-and-trading-platform)

I want to scaling y axis price with decimal. I have tried `priceFormatter()`, and returns the object with format function to format the prices. But, I can't find function like `setPriceFormatter()`

```
widget.chart().priceFormatter();
```

and this the return object

```
{
   type: "price"
   _fractional: false
   _fractionalLength: 0
   _minMove: 1
   _minMove2: undefined
   _priceScale: 1
}
```

By default with user click, it can scale the price value

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFH9f.png)

Answer (score 1):

found it

```
widget.onChartReady(function () {
    widget.mainSeriesPriceFormatter()._priceScale = 10000;
});
```